# How to set win32 menu checked icon to default?

Tags: c++, winapi, menu

I have a win32 `HMENU`, if I set the menu icon by

```
ModifyMenu(hMenu, 2, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_BITMAP, ID_BG_RED, (LPCTSTR)bmpIcon3);
```

The menu icon is changed, however the "checked" checkmark is changed also.
Since the default checkmark is gone after I use `ModifyMenu`, I add another checkmark icon using this:

```
SetMenuItemBitmaps(hMenu, 2, MF_BYPOSITION, NULL, checkedIcon);
```

I tried using a similar icon instead, but looks very weird like this:

[image]
And this is my icon
[image]

I have tried a 22*22 or 20*20 bmp file, however they always became smaller when checked item is not on the first menu item.

The size can't exactly match the original checkmark like this one:

[image]

Is there any way I can get the default checkmark back?

Comment: "The selected and clear bitmaps should be monochrome. The system uses the Boolean AND operator to combine bitmaps with the menu so that the white part becomes transparent and the black part becomes the menu-item color. If you use color bitmaps, the results may be undesirable."

Comment: "Use the GetSystemMetrics function with the CXMENUCHECK and CYMENUCHECK values to retrieve the bitmap dimensions."